# angular ng-click ng-show stopped working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

I have this small code fragment:

```
<li ng-if="vm.data.Description" ng-click="expand=!expand">{{vm.data.Description}}</li>
<li ng-if="vm.data.LongDescription" ng-show="expand">{{vm.data.LongDescription}}</li>
```

vm.data.Description and vm.data.LongDescription contain values.

LongDescription is hidden, but when I click on Description, it becomes visible.
I toggle like this by setting **expand** flag true or false.

**Why this code is not working ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-if uses child scope that is why you cannot link your primitive variable (expand), so if you can just change expand to vm.expand and it will work...

and your ng-show is not needed there you already have ng-if for it...

```
<li ng-if="vm.data.Description" ng-click="vm.expand=!vm.expand">{{vm.data.Description}}</li>
<li ng-if="vm.data.LongDescription && vm.expand">{{vm.data.LongDescription}}</li>
```

and here is working [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/1pU856CAQWoQy9hGrObw?p=preview)